# Format output of the test file using sed command

Tags: unix

tried this to  ( `sed 's/\^/||\'\^'\||/g' best4.txt>best5.txt` )   is not woking need to substitute `^` to `'^'`.

if a text file contain below content (`best4.txt`).

```
SELECT FED1||^||FED2||^||FED3 FROM TEMP;
```

output of the file should be (`best5.txt`).

```
SELECT FED1||'^'||FED2||'^'||FED3 FROM TEMP;
```

Comment: 'not working' is not enough info. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
sed "s|\^|'^'|g" best4.txt>best5.txt
```

With sed, the **^** sign, just like in vim, means beginning of a line. In your case you want the **^** sign to be interpreted as the sign and not the beginning of a line, so since **^** is a special char you have to escape it and in sed/vim you do that adding a backslash (\) in front of it.

If you want to directly replace in the same file you can use `sed -i`

Comment: Thanks for the comment and recommendation!